# Compile Lib Jingle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xcode4, libjingle

I am trying to use the Libjingle library By GYP

I follow the readme
I run the following commands

$ gclient config http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
$ gclient sync --force

But i do not get any libjingle libraries in the folder
Has anyone else faced the problem?.

Is there any good tutorial for Libjingle which would give me step by step instructions?
Thanks in advance
Nitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the depot_tools downloaded and you have to make sure that you add the depot_tools folder to your path.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH="$PATH":path/to/depot_tools
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked.
I am trying to connect an android device and Computer for filesharing any tutorials you can point me too?